# Unity public variable returning previous value in separate script - how to fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

A public variable is returning its previous value when referenced in a different script in Unity.

Basically, I want to compare two variables, one of them being `oppChoice`. I set it to public string before this function:

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (BS.triggerOpp) //BS another script referenced before Update()
        {
            string[] rpsChoice = { "R", "P", "S" };

            System.Random random = new System.Random();
            oppChoice = rpsChoice[random.Next(0, rpsChoice.Length)];

            if (oppChoice == "R")
            {
                spriteRenderer.sprite = rockSprite;

            }
            else if (oppChoice == "P")
            {
                spriteRenderer.sprite = paperSprite;

            }
            else if (oppChoice == "S")
            {
                spriteRenderer.sprite = scissorsSprite;
            }

            anim.SetTrigger("IsRespond");

            BS.triggerOpp = false;

            Debug.Log(oppChoice);
        }
    }
}
```

Every time `BS.triggerOpp == true` the variable gets assigned either "R", "P" or "S" and the sprite changes accordingly. When I use `Debug.Log` to print it through this script, the output always matches the sprite.

Since I want this variable to get compared with another one, I made a new script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScoreWhatBeatsWhat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ButtonsScript player; //the other variable's script
    public OppRandomScript opp;  //oppChoice's script
  
    public void CompareTwoVariables()
    {
       //code comparing the two variables NOT altering opp.oppChoice in ANY way

       Debug.Log(opp.oppChoice);
    }
}
```

Both of these functions are triggered at the same time by the click of a button and they are both printing out the value of `oppChoice`, so they should be printing out the same value. When running the game, the functions are triggered more than once, therefore the variable's value changes every time. The script in which the variable is originally set (1st one) returns the correct value, however the other script, in which it's only referenced, returns it's previous value.

So when I ran the game, if the first value that is randomized after trigger is "P", `Debug.Log(oppsChoice)` from the first script will print "P", but `Debug.Log(opp.oppChoice)` from the second one won't print out anything. Second time it's triggered the first script will print whatever the new value is, for example "R", but the second script will return the previous value, "P". This just keeps going every time the functions are triggered and opp.oppChoice is always printing  the previous value. There are no errors and everything but that runs exactly how it's supposed to, but I can't continue with my project until the variable returns the correct value in both cases, as it is part of the core game mechanic.

I've been trying to find a solution for almost an entire day but nothing seems to work.

I tried:

- making the `oppChoice` variable global
- altering the first script so that instead of Update() and if (trigger) it was a simple public function that I attached to `OnClick()`
- storing `oppChoice`'s value in a different variable and printing that one through the second script
- tweaking every little thing

** None of that worked. **

[Every attempt returns this in the Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJpng.png)

I spend hours looking it up and I found that apparently something called "Events and Delegates" might help, but this is my first Unity project and, from what I read it seems way to advanced for my level.

I don't know what else to do so any input as to how to solve this issue would be really helpful :) Thanks!

Comment: would suggest you aren't looking at the same copy of the script

Comment: @BugFinder Could you maybe elaborate? Sorry, I'm kinda completely new to this so the more you can specify the better :) thanks

Comment: It sounds like theres more than 1 xopy od the script in the scene. Or you set the value after testing it

Comment: @BugFinder Debug.Log is the last command on both scripts, and I can't find any duplicates in the assets folder

Comment: No. Not in the asset folder. As i said in the scene.  Your debug print screen shows no details whatsoever so is useless

Comment: @BugFinder No duplicates in the scene either, the script is attached to only one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed! After a lot of trial and error, I finally looked into events and used an event to alert my second script when the `oppChoice`'s value is changed. Had to create another script and alter a few things, but at the end of the day, it finally returns the correct value!